# How to put <img> exactly under another <img> in html?

Tags: html, css

I want to put two images on the left and a table on the right. At the moment I have one picture on the left, a table on the right and a blank space in the place where I want my another `<img>`. When I try to put my second `<img>` it remains on the left but under the table as it is 2x longer than the first image. Here's my code:

```css
th { color: white; padding: 10px; }
td { color: white; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid aqua; }
tr { opacity: 0.8; }
tr:hover {background-color: #72FFBB;}

#td {
 opacity: 0.2;
}

.table{
    height: 654px;
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
    border: 2px solid aqua;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!-- first picture -->
 <div> <img id="VY_Canis_Majoris_vs_sun"  src="VY_Canis_Majoris_vs_sun.png" width="44%" height="50%" style= "float: left;"> </div>
 
 <!-- the one that should be under the first picture, but it is next to it --> 
  <div> <img id="VY_Canis_Majoris_vs_sun" src="Sol_VY_Canis_Majoris.png" width="44%" height="50%" style="z-index: -1;"> </div>

 <div  class="table"> <table width="100%" height="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td> text</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mass</td>
    <td>8 solar mass units </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Radius</td>
    <td>1,708 ± 192 R☉</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Luminosity</td>
    <td>340,000 L☉</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Surface gravity</td>
    <td>Surface gravity (log g) −0.5 cgs</td> 
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Temperature</td>
    <td>3,365±134 K</td> 
  </tr>
</table> </div>
```

Comment: Use this URL `https://loremflickr.com/320/240` to create images use the numbers for `/width/height` of your images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the two pictures in one div

```
<div class="myimg">
<!-- first picture --> 
<img id="VY_Canis_Majoris_vs_sun"  src="VY_Canis_Majoris_vs_sun.png" width="44%" height="50%" style= "float: left;">

 <!-- the one that should be under the first picture, but it is next to it --> 
  <img id="VY_Canis_Majoris_vs_sun" src="Sol_VY_Canis_Majoris.png" width="44%" height="50%" style="z-index: -1;"> </div>

 <div  class="table"> <table width="100%" height="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td> text</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mass</td>
    <td>8 solar mass units </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Radius</td>
    <td>1,708 ± 192 R☉</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Luminosity</td>
    <td>340,000 L☉</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Surface gravity</td>
    <td>Surface gravity (log g) −0.5 cgs</td> 
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Temperature</td>
    <td>3,365±134 K</td> 
  </tr>
</table> </div>
```

then add this css

```
.myimg{
    float: left;
    width: 44%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give `float:left` to both image div tag.

```css
th { color: white; padding: 10px; }
td { color: white; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid aqua; }
tr { opacity: 0.8; }
tr:hover {background-color: #72FFBB;}
.d1{
float:left;
height:100px;
width:100px;
}
#td {
 opacity: 0.2;
}

.table{
    height: 654px;
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
    border: 2px solid aqua;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!-- first picture -->
 <div class="d1"> <img id="VY_Canis_Majoris_vs_sun"  src="VY_Canis_Majoris_vs_sun.png" width="44%" height="50%" style= "float: left;"> </div>
 
 <!-- the one that should be under the first picture, but it is next to it --> 
  <div class="d1"> <img id="VY_Canis_Majoris_vs_sun" src="Sol_VY_Canis_Majoris.png" width="44%" height="50%" style="z-index: -1;"> </div>

 <div  class="table"> <table width="100%" height="100%">
   <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td> text</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mass</td>
    <td>8 solar mass units </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Radius</td>
    <td>1,708 ± 192 R☉</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Luminosity</td>
    <td>340,000 L☉</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Surface gravity</td>
    <td>Surface gravity (log g) −0.5 cgs</td> 
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Temperature</td>
    <td>3,365±134 K</td> 
  </tr>
</table> </div>
```

Comment: you have give local image src path so i don't have idea of how big your image is. that's why i gave it my own height and width;

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```css
th {
  color: white; padding: 10px;
}

td {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid aqua;
}

tr {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #72FFBB;
}

#td {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.table{
  height: 654px;
  float: left;
  width: 55%;
  border: 2px solid aqua;
  text-align:center;
}

.wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

div img {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.table {
  float: right;
  width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <img id="VY_Canis_Majoris_vs_sun"  src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRDAYrQr9qgT2W00EV_CoCahFki3Vw4lSMNt81k9FCSTXoKT8TY2w" width="44%" height="50%">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="VY_Canis_Majoris_vs_sun" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEnn9dYYZlciBKfaHCw17-dUgRPX3nq5_6-kV1ua-LIsId5g43uA" width="44%" height="50%" style="z-index: -1;">
    </div>
</div>
<div  class="table">
  <table width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr>
   <td>text</td>
   <td> text</td> 
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Mass</td>
   <td>8 solar mass units </td> 
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Radius</td>
   <td>1,708 ± 192 R☉</td> 
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Luminosity</td>
   <td>340,000 L☉</td> 
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Surface gravity</td>
   <td>Surface gravity (log g) −0.5 cgs</td> 
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Temperature</td>
   <td>3,365±134 K</td> 
 </tr>
  </table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for:

```css
.container,
.images-container {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  flex-direction: row;
}
.images-container,.table-container {
  width:50%;
}

.images-container {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.images-container img{
  max-width:100%;
  height:200px;
  object-fit:cover;
}

/* Table styling */
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
table#t01 {
    width: 100%;    
    background-color: #f1f1c1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='images-container'>
    <img src="http://ste.india.com/sites/default/files/2016/12/30/559004-301216-gs-tch-10.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.dailypioneer.com/uploads/main/mn_story_image/T330_158723_Untitled-2.gif" />
  </div>
  <div class='table-container'>
    <table id='t01' style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group your images into 1 div and float this to the left.

```
<div id="pictures">
   <img id="VY_Canis_Majoris_vs_sun" src="https://picsum.photos/400/400">
   <img id="VY_Canis_Majoris_vs_sun" src="https://picsum.photos/400/400?image=42">
</div>
```

In your css you can give this div a width of 50% (and float it)

```
#pictures {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

If you want your pictures under each other you can put display block on the images and make them fill the space (width: 100%)

```
#pictures img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

You put a border on your table so to make it fit you can put the width on 50% - 4px (2px border on each side). Use calc (short for calculate) for this:

```
.table {
    width: calc(50% - 4px);
    ...
}
```

Here you can find all the code together: https://jsbin.com/rejuburaka/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use `<img />` tag under another `<img />` tag because `<img />` is a single line html tag. You can do something like this

```
<style>
   .full-div{
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0 auto;
   }
   .left-side{
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0 auto;
   }
   .first-div,.second-div,.third-div{
      width: 33%;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0 auto;
   }
</style>
<div class="full-div">
    <div class="left-side">
        <div class="first-div">
            <img src="your image source" />
        </div>
        <div class="second-div">
            <img src="your image source" />
        </div>
        <div class="third-div">
            <img src="your image source" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-side">
     your table here
    </div>
</div>
```